# Node.js unable to import ES6 module

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to separate my routes to a separate module in `routes.js` and then importing in `app.js`. I'm getting a lot of errors in the console.

`internal/modules/esm/default_resolve.js:96
  let url = moduleWrapResolve(specifier, parentURL);
            ^
Error: Cannot find module /Users/rhoxh/Desktop/24/routes imported from /Users/rhoxh/Desktop/24/app.js
    at Loader.resolve [as _resolve] (internal/modules/esm/default_resolve.js:96:13)
    at Loader.resolve (internal/modules/esm/loader.js:73:33)
    at Loader.getModuleJob (internal/modules/esm/loader.js:147:40)
    at ModuleWrap.<anonymous> (internal/modules/esm/module_job.js:41:40)
    at link (internal/modules/esm/module_job.js:40:36) {
  code: 'ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND'
}`

routes.js

```
import express from 'express';

const router = express.Router();

router.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('home page');
});

export default router;
```

app.js

```
import express from 'express';
import { router } from './routes';

const app = express();
const PORT = 8080;

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server running at: http://localhost:${PORT}/`);
});

// Routes
app.use('/', router);
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Have you tried to change `import { router } from './routes';` to `import router  from './routes.js';` ?

Comment: which version of node do you use? Do you use a bundler or babel?

Comment: yes i have already tried that. no babel and node v 13.3.0

Comment: try full filename `'./routes.js'`

Comment: this works but why?

Comment: What works?????

Comment: with the js ext it works

Comment: Because that is the name of the file.

Comment: yes but its supposed to work without the .js like always

Comment: that's the spec of es6 modules. You have to provide full path.

Comment: with babel you don't need `.js` extension. But when you work directly with es6 modules in node, you have to use extensions. The same goes for using modules in browsers

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You need to use the full file name:

```
import router from './routes.js';
```

From the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import):

> **module-name**
>
> The module to import from. This is often a relative or
>   absolute path name to the .js file containing the module. Certain
>   bundlers may permit or require the use of the extension; check your
>   environment. Only single quoted and double quoted Strings are allowed.

Comment: No matter the reasons, this makes for an extremely frustrating development experience. Node should prioritize fixing this IMO.

Comment: @AdityaAnand: [there's a flag for that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64453859/directory-import-is-not-supported-resolving-es-modules-with-node-js/65588027#65588027).

Answer (score 2):

You can check this link it could help you https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/27408

You can try to use `--es-module-specifier-resolution=node` as it says.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone looking for a typescript solution use the .js file extension of your transpiled files.

```
// index.ts file.
import router from './routes.js';
```

Answer (score 0):

You are destructuring your import yet you are exporting as `default`.
When you import a default there is no need for destructuring

`import  router  from './routes';`

You can use destructuring when you are using either a named export

`export const router = express.Router()`

or you pull out a property from the `default export`

```
export default {
  router: express.Router()
}
```

Comment: Im not using destructing anymore and still the same error

Comment: While it might be true that also no named imports should be used, the error clearly states "*Cannot find module*"

Comment: the file is in the same dir as app.js?