# 'Directory import is not supported resolving ES modules' with Node.js

Tags: node.js, es6-modules

I'm using Node.js **v14.13.0**.

**app.js** file:

```
import database from './database';

database();
```

**database/index.js** file:

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';

export default connect = async () => {
    try {
        await mongoose.connect('...', { });
    } catch (error) {}
};
```

In **package.json** I added `"type": "module"`.

After running the app I get the following error:

> Error [ERR_UNSUPPORTED_DIR_IMPORT]: Directory import
> '/Users/xx/Desktop/Projects/node-starter/src/database' is not
> supported resolving ES modules imported from
> /Users/xx/Desktop/Projects/node-starter/src/app.js

Comment: when using type module you have to do it like: `import database from './database.js'` don't forget .js

Comment: Do you mean `'database/index.js'`? it doesn't work.

Comment: I mean when importing make sure you add .js at the end of import like `import database from './database.js'` or you can use `ems` module and in your package.json just do `nodemon -r esm main.js`

Comment: @webcoder database.js doesn't exist so that doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 88, accepted):

With ES6 modules you can not (yet?) import directories. Your import should look like this:

```
import database from "./database/index.js"
```

Comment: The import can be kept as in the OP, if the [`--experimental-specifier-resolution=node` flag](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65588027/1269037) is passed.

Comment: Unfortunately not any more. `--experimental-specifier-resolution` was first available in Node.js v12, and last available in v18, as of Node v19 it no longer exists and you have to use a custom loader instead.

Comment: Bummer, this is one of many things they are breaking.  So sad to see JavaScript in its prime but simple bad decisions like this really makes it a liability to use.  It will be a while, but I see it coming, all good things have to come to an end.

Comment: @jcalfee314 I honestly don't see this as an issue, all you need is an IDE that can resolve imports for you.

Comment: Can typescript automatically convert directory imports?

Comment: see also `resolveFullPaths` of [ts-alias](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tsc-alias)

Comment: following @DanDascalescu works, but not in every node version: for example, version 20.9.0 doesn't work, whereas 19.5 does

Answer (score 49):

What happens here is that Node [mandates](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#esm_mandatory_file_extensions) using an extension in `import` statements and also states,

> Directory indexes (e.g. `'./startup/index.js'`) must also be fully specified.

Your `import database from './database';` statement doesn't specify the `index.js`. You can add `index.js` as suggested in another answer, but that approach doesn't look elegant [in TypeScript projects](https://github.com/dandv/typescript-modern-project#import-your-own-modules-without-specifying-an-extension), when you'd end up importing a `.js` file from a `.ts` one.

You can change this Node extension resolution behavior by passing the `--experimental-specifier-resolution=node` [flag](https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_experimental_specifier_resolution_mode). This will work and will keep your code unchanged:

**app.js**

```js
import database from './database';
database();
```

Run as: `node --experimental-specifier-resolution=node app.js`.

A Node developer admitted that the documentation [wasn't that clear](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/27408#issuecomment-598314461).

Comment: doesn't work for me and nodejs 20.9.0

Answer (score 1):

TValidator's answer is somewhat right, you can use babel to resolve this issue.
However, you must install @babel/core, @babel/node, @babel/preset-env.
And, you must make [babel.config.json](https://babeljs.io/setup#installation) like belows;

```
{
    "presets": ["@babel/preset-env"]
}
```

You should stay babel.config.json in the root folder of your project.
Now, you don't have to set "type": "module" to the package.json.

Comment: this is right. solution described is true.

Answer (score 0):

According to nodejs [documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#esm_import_statements), directory imports doesn't work

Comment: That's correct, but not quite [the whole story](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65588027/1269037).

Answer (score 0):

With ES6 modules you can not (yet?) import directories.

Here you can see I made this changes and it worked for me this are my two files below and I needed to write require  to import user for it but in ES6 it doesn't support require so in my solution I created the export default of users and it comes with sequelize and datatypes values so now I created import of users above in index.js file so I can use those values without using require.

Also you have to add (.js) extension in the imported files path just like I did in index.js files second line.

Your import should look like this:

Index.js

```
import { DataTypes, Sequelize } from "sequelize";
**import Users from "./users.js";**

const sequelize = new Sequelize("Users", "root", "", {
  host: "localhost",
  dialect: "mysql",
  pool: { max: 5, min: 0, idle: 10000 },
});
sequelize
  .authenticate()
  .then(() => {
    console.log("Connected !");
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log("Error", err);
  });

const db = {};

db.sequelize = Sequelize;
db.sequelize = sequelize;

**db.users = Users(sequelize, DataTypes);**

db.sequelize.sync().then(() => {
  console.log("YES Re-Sync !");
});

export default sequelize;
```

Users.js

```
const Users = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
sequelize.define(
"Users",
{
  name: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING,
  },
  email: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING,
    defaultValue: "kishandobariyadk7301@gmail.com",
  },
  gender: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING,
  },
},
{
  // timestamps: false,
  // updatedAt: false,
  // createdAt: false,
  // createdAt: created_at,
  // updatedAt: modified_at,
  // engine: "Kishan",
}
`);
};


export default Users;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're getting this error as a result of importing a third-party library, you *might* have to move your dependency from `devDependencies` to `dependencies`. This is certainly not something that fits all use cases but still might make sense in your specific context.

This is what solved my issue:

```
// Before
"devDependencies": {
  "third-party-lib": "version"
}

// After
"dependencies": {
  "third-party-lib": "version"
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use babel. I used following babel library in node project and every ES6 features work properly.

```
"devDependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-class-properties": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.6.1"
  }
```

Although it may be old version but you can use latest version.

Comment: I was using babel and of course, it was working, but I decided to remove it as a dependency because it doesn't bring much to the table. I can use all es6 without using babe.
I added `type: "module"` in my package.json so it should work.  
Thanks for the suggestion anyway

Comment: You didn't mention you were using babel already. If I knew I never try to give any suggestion for your negative vote. Thanks for your negative vote.

Comment: it's not me who gave the negative vote. sorry about that.

Comment: Sorry. I was not aware.

Comment: I don't have much knowledge about point system in Stack Overflow but I'm very much sure you gave me some points. Thank you so much for that. Normally I don't perticipate anywhere. Recently I lauched one of my product 'TValidator' and trying to market in organic way. That is the reasson why I started participating in this platform but suddenly I was blocked by admin for -2 points. Sorry for my rude behavior and Thanks again.

Comment: Babel is a stopgap solution. So are [Node flags](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65588027/1269037), but they're far lighter and faster.

Comment: TValidator, you must make babel.config.json file. I vote your answer to up, now 0 ^-^